# Julia subset function not skipping missing values?

Tags: dataframe, julia, subset

I have this code snippet which works fine when my filtering function checks for missing values and throws them out, too:

```
function subset_simple(code)::Bool
if ismissing(code)
    return false
end 
code == 1 || code == 2 || code == 3
end

fe2=subset(fe,:value => ByRow(subset_simple),skipmissing=true);
```

If I remove the `ismissing` bit, then `subset` complains:

`TypeError: non-boolean (Missing) used in boolean context`

I find that very strange thinking that `subset` was wholly designed to skip over missing values. Why did I have to instruct my function to check for it, too?

Comment: The `skipmissing` parameter (according to REPL help) applies to the output of the function. Therefore to achieve the same functionality without the `if` condition in `subset_simple`, you can use the decorated function `passmissing(subset_simple)` and then there is no need for the `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan is right. However, to expand on it you have the following options which I would find elegant:

```
subset(fe,:value => ByRow(in((1, 2, 3))), skipmissing=true)
```

or

```
subset(fe,:value => ByRow(in(Set((1, 2, 3)))))
```

Note that the difference is because:

```
julia> in((1,2,3))(missing)
missing

julia> in(Set((1,2,3)))(missing)
false
```

and for a large number of options `Set` would be in general faster.

Comment: Thank you Bogumił! Can you please explain the construction with `in`? I tried to glean it from here https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.in but somehow the syntax/bracketing evades me?

Comment: Basically, is in(args) a functor of some sort where in(args) becomes a callable object?

Comment: Yes, please type in `? in` in the terminal and this will be the first documentation entry. `in(item, collection)` is the same as `in(collection)(item)`.

Comment: Bogumił, I suppose you are saying 'yes' to a functor based on the line: "Create a function that checks whether its argument is in collection"? Great :-)

Comment: Technically `in(collection)` would be called higher other function, e.g. a function returning a new function. You could also say that `in(collection)` is partial function application (you fix one argument of `in` leaving the second unfixed. (however, Julia, as opposed to e.g. Haskell, does not have functionalities like currying built into the language, so every time such things as `in(collection)` are defined they need a custom implementation). Technically what is returned is a callable object of `Fix2` type that is defined to be a subtype of `Function`.